# Ruby open_uri error NoMethodError: undefined method `strip' for 10:Fixnum

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, open-uri

When I use this everything is fine:

```
html = open("http://"+self.url).read
```

But when I add a user agent:

```
html = open("http://"+self.url, "User-Agent" => "Ruby", 'read_timeout' => 10 ).read
```

I get:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `strip' for 10:Fixnum
    from /Users/a_user/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/http/header.rb:17:in `block in initialize_http_header'
```

What is wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pass `10` as string not integer value

```
html = open("http://"+self.url, "User-Agent" => "Ruby", 'read_timeout' => '10' ).read
```

**[`OpenURI`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.0/libdoc/open-uri/rdoc/OpenURI.html)** is trying to run [**`strip`**](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/String.html#method-i-strip) on the value

Answer (score -1):

It seems it objects to the key being a string. Try turning 'read_timeout' into a symbol:

```
html = open("http://"+self.url, "User-Agent" => "Ruby", read_timeout: 10 ).read
```

I could replicate your error with the 'read_timeout' but changing it to a symbol fixed it here anyway.